# How to get an array of selected attributes only?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying the get the users ids of a team, the team - user relation is:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('users', 'team_user_table', 'team_id','user_id');
    }
```

I try to get list of user_ids:

```
$user_ids= $team->users()->select('user_id')->get()
```

But I get array of objects instead of simple ids as in the image
How can I just get a simple array of user_id like [1, 5, 7, 8] ?

[image]

Comment: Try `$team->users()->lists('user_id')` or `$team->users()->lists('user_id'->all()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck) method.

```
$user_ids = $team->users()->pluck('user_id')->all();
```

Also, do not use `lists()` as it is [depracated](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade) and will be removed:

> **Deprecations**
>
> The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and **will be removed in
>   the 5.3 release in June 2016**:
>
> The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query
>   builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature
>   remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `get()`, use `lists()`. Like this:

```
$user_ids = $team->users()->lists('user_id')->all();
```

The `lists()` call means to get only the data, and the `all()` makes it into an array rather than a collection.